# Bind mount - reducing hard disk spin up

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I'm trying to reduce hard disk spin up on my system (Raspbian Buster).

My system has a read-only root (to mitigate unexpected power interruptions), with `home`, `srv` and `var` mounted read-write on an external hard disk (`sda`) using a bind mount:

```
# findmnt
TARGET                           SOURCE           FSTYPE  OPTIONS
/                                /dev/mmcblk0p2   ext4    ro,noatime,errors=remo
├─/mnt/ssd                       /dev/sdb1        ext4    rw,relatime
├─/mnt/hdd                       /dev/sda1        ext4    rw,relatime
│ └─/mnt/hdd/var/log             /dev/sdb1[/var/log]
│                                                 ext4    rw,relatime
├─/srv                           /dev/sda1[/srv]  ext4    rw,relatime
├─/home                          /dev/sda1[/home] ext4    rw,relatime
└─/var                           /dev/sda1[/var]  ext4    rw,relatime
  └─/var/log                     /dev/sdb1[/var/log]
                                                  ext4    rw,relatime
```

Using `fatrace`, I found most of the disk accesses to `/var` were caused by logs, so underneath the `/var` directory I've put a bind mount so that `/var/log` sits on a SSD (`sdb`) - note this SSD is quite small so can't hold all of `var`.

My questions are:

- Is this approach a sound way to reduce hard disk spin ups? For example, because `/var/log` (SSD) is a bind mount inside `/var` (HDD), will the hard disk spin up anyway?
- There are various daemons reading/writing to other parts of `/var`. I could put bind mounts for each one but that will quickly become complicated. Are there any other approaches I could try?

Comment: "_Is this approach a sound way to reduce hard disk spin ups?_"... reasonable, but it contradicts your upfront reasoning about making root read-only...? What's wrong with the disk spinning up? Is your SSD really fragile enough to warrant moving things away? (is your "_SSD_" an SD card?)

Comment: Well, `mmcblk` almost always indicates an SD card, and those really tend to fail much faster than SATA or NVMe SSDs...

Comment: Correct, `mmcblk0` is an SD card and `sdb` is a USB drive. Read only root on the former helps [mitigate unexpected power interruptions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=36533) - if the USB drive corrupts then that won't take down the whole system. I prefer an idle hard disk so there is less noise when it is sitting unused.